# How to set Jira's default timezone?

Tags: jira

My Ubuntu server is EST, but all times in Jira are UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a JVM parameter:

-Duser.timezone=EST

Add this to the JAVA_OPTS variable in setenv.sh (or setenv.bat if you're on Windows) in the bin subdirectory of your installation and restart JIRA.

Comment: Fabulous, thanks.  I played with the setting further and used -Duser.timezone=America/New_York to get Jira to pick up EDT properly.

Comment: To elaborate on setting JVM parameters on startup: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Setting+Properties+and+Options+on+Startup

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice too keep all the systems on UTC, database and servers.

The only place where people should use the local timezone is the last step, the client.

Otherwise sooner or later you will reach the point where you get the datatime altered, especially when migrating data.